# Loop through Series to find which have the same index value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, time-series

I'd like to concatenate/merge my pandas Series together. This is my data structure (For extra information)

```
dictionary = { 'a':{'1','2','3','4'}, 'b':{'1','2','3','4'} }
```

There are many more values at both levels, and each number corresponds to a series that contains timeseries data. I would like to merge all of 'a' together into one dataframe, the only trouble is that some of the data is yearly, some quarterly and some monthly.

so what I'm looking to do is loop through my data, something like this:

```
for level1 in dictData:
     for level2 in dictData[level1]:
         dictData[level1][level2].index.equals(dictData[level1][level2])
```

but obviously here I'm just comparing the series to itself! How would I compare each element to all the others? I know I'm missing something fairly fundamental. Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's some samples of actual data:

```
{'noT10101': {'A191RL':             Gross domestic product
1947-01-01                    -1.1
1947-04-01                    -1.0
1947-07-01                    -0.8
1947-10-01                     6.4
1948-01-01                     4.1
...                            ...
2020-01-01                    -5.0
2020-04-01                   -31.4
2020-07-01                    33.4
2020-10-01                     4.3
2021-01-01                     6.4

[370 rows x 1 columns], 'DGDSRL':             Goods
1947-01-01    2.9
1947-04-01    7.4
1947-07-01    2.7
1947-10-01    1.5
1948-01-01    2.0
...           ...
2020-01-01    0.1
2020-04-01  -10.8
2020-07-01   47.2
2020-10-01   -1.4
2021-01-01   26.6

[370 rows x 1 columns], 'A191RP':             Gross domestic product, current dollars
1947-01-01                                      9.7
1947-04-01                                      4.7
1947-07-01                                      6.0
1947-10-01                                     17.3
1948-01-01                                     10.0
...                                             ...
2020-01-01                                     -3.4
2020-04-01                                    -32.8
2020-07-01                                     38.3
2020-10-01                                      6.3
2021-01-01                                     11.0

[370 rows x 1 columns], 'DSERRL':             Services
1947-01-01       0.4
1947-04-01       5.9
1947-07-01      -0.8
1947-10-01      -2.1
1948-01-01       2.7
...              ...
2020-01-01      -9.8
2020-04-01     -41.8
2020-07-01      38.0
2020-10-01       4.3
2021-01-01       4.2

[370 rows x 1 columns],
```

As you can see, dictionary key 'not10101' corresponds to a series of keys 'A191RL', 'DGDSRL', 'A191RP', etc. whose associated value is a Series. So when I am accessing .index I am looking at the index of that Series aka the datetime values. In this example they all match but in some cases they don't.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I'm a bit confused with your examples. For instance, you are looping through a dictionary but trying to access the index attribute. The numbers are supposed to be the data frames in your real data, is that it?

Comment: @HemersonTacon thank you for your answer and comment, please check my edit

Comment: I've updated my answer as well. I still suggest the same approach. If I understood your question correctly it should work on your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `concat` function. It would be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(size=5), 
                index=pd.Timestamp("2021-01-01") + np.arange(5) * pd.Timedelta(days=365),
                dtype=float)
df2 = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(size=12), 
                index=pd.Timestamp("2021-01-15") + np.arange(12) * pd.Timedelta(days=30),
                dtype=float)
dictData= {"a": {"series": df, "same_series": df}, "b": {"series":df, "different_series": df2}}
new_dict = {}
for level1 in dictData:
    new_dict[level1] = pd.concat(list(dictData[level1].values()))
```

Notice that I tried to mimic both yearly and monthly granularity. I want to say with this is that it doesn't matter the granularity of the series that are being concatenated.
The result will be something like this:

```
{'a': 2021-01-01    0.213574
 2022-01-01    0.263514
 2023-01-01    0.627435
 2024-01-01    0.388753
 2024-12-31    0.990316
 2021-01-01    0.213574
 2022-01-01    0.263514
 2023-01-01    0.627435
 2024-01-01    0.388753
 2024-12-31    0.990316
 dtype: float64,
 'b': 2021-01-01    0.213574
 2022-01-01    0.263514
 2023-01-01    0.627435
 2024-01-01    0.388753
 2024-12-31    0.990316
 2021-05-01    0.614485
 2021-05-31    0.611967
 2021-06-30    0.820435
 2021-07-30    0.839613
 2021-08-29    0.507669
 2021-09-28    0.471049
 2021-10-28    0.550482
 2021-11-27    0.723789
 2021-12-27    0.209169
 2022-01-26    0.664584
 2022-02-25    0.901832
 2022-03-27    0.946750
 dtype: float64}
```

Take a look at the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: I've done as you suggested and received many NaN values and duplicate date entries in my concatenated dataframe. Your suggestion is nonetheless helpful as I'm definitely a step closer to my solution, I'll update later today once I've solved this.